# Android path. Merge path array

Tags: java, arrays, path, merge, bezier

I have a surfaceview custom class. I drawn in it canvas an array of paths. This paths coordinates are generated by view dynamically added with inflate view. This is my run code:

```
public void run() {
    while (isItOK == true) {
        // perform canvas drawing
        if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            continue;
        }

        c = holder.lockCanvas();
        c.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,null);

        if (ii>jj) {
            for(aaa = 2; aaa <= 50; aaa++) {    
                if (rr[aaa] != null) {
                    // MIDDLEX = ss[aaa].getX();
                    // MIDDLEY = ss[aaa].getY();
                    path[aaa] = new Path(); 
                    path[aaa].moveTo(rr[aaa-1].getX() + 40, rr[aaa-1].getY() - 80);
                    path[aaa].cubicTo(rr[aaa-1].getX() + 40, rr[aaa-1].getY() - 80, ss[aaa].getX(), ss[aaa].getY(), rr[aaa].getX() + 40, rr[aaa].getY() - 80);
                    path[aaa].setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
                    c.drawPath(path[aaa], paint);
                }
```

`path[aaa]` in an array of paths. `rr[aaa]` is the array of view dynamically added, and represent the start point and the end  point of a bezier curve. `ss[aa]` is an array of view dynamically added and represent the control point  of a bezier curve. How can I merge `path[aaa]` into one single path? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is, generally, mathematically impossible to merge two Bezier curves of the same order (say, quadratic or cubic), and end up with another Bezier curve of that same order, except when your curves are all the result of curve splitting. If you just have "some paths", merging them will always be lossy (you end up with an approximation), and you'll certainly not be able to merge all paths into a single curve. As simple guideline: if your collection of curves "bends" more than once, you already can't merge it to a quadratic curve, if it "bends" more than twice, you can't merge to cubic.

Comment: I think you are right. My goal is to select the pixels wrapped by the paths. I will try to do that calculating the curves formula, knowing the three control points, then generating horizontal lines and find the intersections points with the paths (also is an infinity of curves that can be draw by three points, i will try to do that with Quadratic Functions)

Comment: Please note how your comment explains that what you *want* isn't actually what you were *asking*. It might be a good idea to delete this question, and then ask about what you want to do instead as a new question.